# Web8 : BundleType none, when creating new bundle

Tags: bundles, web8.5

I am upgrading Trdion 2013sp1 to SDLWEB8.5 version. Try to create new bundle in sdlweb8.5. I got None value for Bundle Type. it`s same working fine in sdl tridion2013 sp1. any suggestion to fix this issue in sdlweb8.5.

SDL Tridion 2013sp1 Code:

```
c.MetaSchemaDropdown.setDisabled(false);
c.MetaSchemaDropdown.setValue(tcmIDmSchema); // the corresponding Metadata Schema
var value = c.MetaSchemaDropdown.getValue();
var metadataSchema = value ? $models.getItem(value) : null; // Does it has a value.. and we will !
var item = $display.getView().getItem();    
this.setMetadataSchema(value, this); // Setting Schema

$display.getView().applyFieldsSchema(metadataSchema, true); /
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After 2 days R & D I got solution for this issue.

```
SDLWeb.Tridion.Methods.setMetadataSchema = function (value, context)
{
    var item = $display.getView().getItem();
    item.properties.metadataSchemaId = value;
    item.updateValue("/tcm:*/tcm:Data/tcm:MetadataSchema/@xlink:href", value || $const.URINULL, context);
};
```